# TensorFlow Cost Value return NAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

I am making a simple Logistic Regression Model using Tensorflow. But the cost value is always returning nan.

My data sets are divided into x_data and y_data. x_data is a coordinate in an image and y_data is 1 or 0 since my image is black and white. I am trying to find a dividing line between white color and black color.

```
def train(input,iterations):
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(777)  # for reproducibility

x_data = []
y_data = []

i_dim = input.shape[0]
j_dim = input.shape[1]

for i in range(i_dim):
    for j in range(j_dim):
        x_data.append([j,i_dim-i-1])
        y_data.append([int(input[i,j])])

# placeholders for a tensor that will be always fed.
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='bias')

# Hypothesis using sigmoid: tf.div(1., 1. + tf.exp(tf.matmul(X, W)))
hypothesis = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)

# cost/loss function
cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y * tf.log(hypothesis) + (1 - Y) *
                       tf.log(1 - hypothesis))

train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cost)

# Launch graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize TensorFlow variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for step in range(iterations):
        cost_val, _ = sess.run([cost, train], feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
        print(step, cost_val)
```

this is my log
`(0, nan)
(1, nan)
(2, nan)
(3, nan)
(4, nan)
(5, nan)
(6, nan)
(7, nan)
(8, nan)
(9, nan)
(10, nan)
(11, nan)
(12, nan)
(13, nan)
(14, nan)
(15, nan)
(16, nan)
(17, nan)
(18, nan)
(19, nan)
(20, nan)`

and so on

Comment: Can `hypothesis` be 1 or 0?

Comment: that is possible

Comment: Then you are trying to compute a log of zero, which is obviously problematic.

Comment: Yup got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your hypothesis is equal to 1, your second part of the loss becomes Y * log(0), hence the nan output. I suggest you to add a small constant inside the logarithm and it should work. Try this

```
cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y*(tf.log(hypothesis+1e-4))+(1-Y)*(tf.log(1-hypothesis+1e-4)))
```

Comment: I have tried this. cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y *( tf.log(hypothesis)+1e-4) + (1 - Y) *
                           (tf.log(1 - hypothesis)+1e-4)) and still not working

Comment: try this cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y *( tf.log(hypothesis + 1e-4)) + (1 - Y) * (tf.log(1 - hypothesis+1e-4)))

Comment: Nice, glad to have helped. Please consider picking this as accepted answer :)